# Send POST request to Rest WS with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, rest, post

Im trying to send a REST request to a WCF Service with javascript.
I have tried the service with a .net client and it works fine
this is my example method in the wcf service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", 
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
bool GuardarJuan(Persona persona);
```

From javascript i have tried these methods:

```
function sendRequest3(){
var datos='{"IdPersona":2,"Nombre":"David BQ"}';
var parameters = JSON.stringify(datos);
        var req=$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RestTEST/GuardarJuan',
            type: 'POST',
            data: parameters,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }
```

And also like this:

```
function sendPost(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RestTEST/GuardarJuan";
    var persona={
        IdPersona: 2,
        Nombre: 'David BQ'
    };
    var parameters = JSON.stringify(persona);
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.send(parameters);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= function X()
        {

             if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
             {
                  alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
             }
        }
```

but none of this work.
It always give me a 405 error Method not allowed or 0x80004005 (NS ERROR FAILURE)

Thanks

EDIT:
Problem solved.. It was the cross-domain problem.
I was doing it with the VS Server, so I changed to IIS and everything worked fine

Comment: What have you ruled out?  Googling gives me http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/31d3f1aa-28b6-4bd7-b031-73b7e7588e6d/  Also, it could be you disabled POST on the IIS server somehow.

Comment: I believe that if you change the port number then you are changing the domain and cross-domain-policies apply, meaning you will have to use JSONP for this request or create a server-side proxy to get the JSON for your JS script.

Answer (score 1):

First, is the "Service" on the same domain as the page you are attempting to talk to the service with?

Second, if you are attempting to use JSONP, you can only use "GET" not "POST" as JSONP simply creates a <script src="service...?callback=somerndmethod"> that wraps the response in somerndmethod(response) ... which executes your expected code.

You may need to use IIS/IISExpress and have both the main, and wcf application on the same host:port.